# How to make thread synchronization without using mutex, semorphore, spinLock and futex?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

This is an interview question, the interview has been done.

How to make thread synchronization without using mutex, semorphore, spinLock and futex ?

Given 5 threads, how to make 4 of them wait for a signal from the left thread at the same point ? 
it means that when all threads (1,2,3,4) execute at a point in their thread function, they stop and wait for 
signal from thread 5 send a signal otherwise they will not proceed.

My idea:

Use global bool variable as a flag, if thread 5 does not set it true, all other threads wait at one point and also set their
flag variable true. After the thread 5 find all threads' flag variables are true, it will set it flag var true.

It is a busy-wait.

Any better ideas ?

Thanks

```
 the pseudo code:
 bool globalflag = false; 
 bool a[10] = {false} ;  
 int main()
 {
  for (int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++)
  pthread_create( threadfunc, i ) ; 

      while(1)
      {
         bool b = true; 
         for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
         {  
              b = a[i] & b ; 
         }
         if (b) break; 
    }
  }
  void threadfunc(i)
  {
   a[i] = true; 
   while(!globalflag); 
  }
```

Comment: Your while(!globalflag) is the equivalent of a spin lock. But I'm afraid I don't understand the question. If you use a signal, what I would do, then you still use a form of semaphore or mutex (albeit hidden by the system.) Without a wait on a signal, you'd have a spinlock. Using the globalflag is good if you can do work while waiting and switch to a different task (or extra task) once the flag is true.

Comment: In addition to what you have here you'd probably have to declare globalflag as volatile to ensure that the compiler actually reads the memory rather than just looking at the code and deciding it can't change value. And use some kind of memory barrier to ensure that values written by one thread are visible in another,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start with an empty linked list of waiting threads.  The head should be set to 0.

Use CAS, compare and swap, to insert a thread at the head of the list of waiters.  If the head =-1, then do not insert or wait.  You can safely use CAS to insert items at the head of a linked list if you do it right.

After being inserted, the waiting thread should wait on SIGUSR1.  Use sigwait() to do this.

When ready, the signaling thread uses CAS to set the head of wait list to -1.  This prevents any more threads from adding themselves to the wait list.  Then the signaling thread iterates the threads in the wait list and calls pthread_kill(&thread, SIGUSR1) to wake up each waiting thread.

If SIGUSR1 is sent before a call to sigwait, sigwait will return immediately.  Thus, there will not be a race between adding a thread to the wait list and calling sigwait.

EDIT:

Why is CAS faster than a mutex?  Laymen's answer (I'm a layman).  Its faster for some things in some situations, because it has lower overhead when there is NO race.  So if you can reduce your concurrent problem down to needing to change 8-16-32-64-128 bits of contiguous memory, and a race is not going to happen very often, CAS wins.  CAS is basically a slightly more fancy/expensive mov instruction right where you were going to do a regular "mov" anyway.  Its a "lock exchng" or something like that.

A mutex on the other hand is a whole bunch of extra stuff, that gets other cache lines dirty and uses more memory barriers, etc.  Although CAS acts as a memory barrier on the x86, x64, etc.  Then of course you have to unlock the mutex which is probably about the same amount of extra stuff.

Here is how you add an item to a linked list using CAS:

```
while (1)
{
  pOldHead = pHead;  <-- snapshot of the world.  Start of the race.
  pItem->pNext = pHead;
  if (CAS(&pHead, pOldHead, pItem))  <-- end of the race if phead still is pOldHead
    break; // success
}
```

So how often do you think your code is going to have multiple threads at that CAS line at the exact same time?  In reality....not very often.  We did tests that just looped adding millions of items with multiple threads at the same time and it happens way less than 1% of the time.  In a real program, it might never happen.

Obviously if there is a race you have to go back and do that loop again, but in the case of a linked list, what does that cost you?

The downside is that you can't do very complex things to that linked list if you are going to use that method to add items to the head.  Try implementing a double linked list.  What a pain.

**EDIT:**

In the code above I use a macro CAS.  If you are using linux, CAS = macro using __sync_bool_compare_and_swap.  See [gcc atomic builtins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html).  If you are using windows, CAS = macro using something like InterlockedCompareExchange.  Here is what an inline function in windows might look like:

```
inline bool CAS(volatile WORD* p, const WORD nOld, const WORD nNew) { 
  return InterlockedCompareExchange16((short*)p, nNew, nOld) == nOld; 
}
inline bool CAS(volatile DWORD* p, const DWORD nOld, const DWORD nNew) {
  return InterlockedCompareExchange((long*)p, nNew, nOld) == nOld; 
}
inline bool CAS(volatile QWORD* p, const QWORD nOld, const QWORD nNew) {
  return InterlockedCompareExchange64((LONGLONG*)p, nNew, nOld) == nOld; 
}
inline bool CAS(void*volatile* p, const void* pOld, const void* pNew) {
  return InterlockedCompareExchangePointer(p, (PVOID)pNew, (PVOID)pOld) == pOld; 
}
```

Comment: thanks , this synchronization has lower overhead than mutex/fuex/semaphore ?

Comment: I benchmarked it about 1-2 years ago, so my memory is fading.  We specifically tried to see how fast we could sleep and wake individual threads.  This method appeared to be about > 10x (or was it 40x?) faster than mutexes and condition variables.  We compared this method to one using an individual mutex/condition variable for each thread.  I never posted my test on here to see it it was flawed or not....  We did not test futexes or semaphores.

Comment: Would you please explain very briefly why CAS is faster than mutex ? it works like futex (no sys call if no lock contention ?) ? thanks!

Comment: @user1000107: if you are interested in performance of locks, see Intel's article here: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/implementing-scalable-atomic-locks-for-multi-core-intel-em64t-and-ia32-architectures/

Comment: @Necrolis, the article is interesting, does Intel have similar things on Linux ? thanks !

Comment: jannb's comment below gives you a little more info about how to setup the signal masks for the threads before you create them.

Comment: @user1000107: I actually haven't come across much for linux, probably cause I the places I've look are windows orientated, however, the user-mode locks described in that article are the best you'll get under any OS

Comment: Can you give me more details for CAS?

Comment: Woops sorry.  CAS is my macro.  If you are using linux, CAS = macro using __sync_bool_compare_and_swap. See gcc atomic builtins. If you are using windows, CAS = macro using something like InterlockedCompareExchange.

Answer (score 1):

1. Choose a signal to use, say SIGUSR1.
2. Use pthread_sigmask to block SIGUSR1.
3. Create the threads (they inherit the signal mask, hence 1 must be done first!)
4. Threads 1-4 call sigwait, blocking until SIGUSR1 is received.
5. Thread 5 calls kill() or pthread_kill 4 times with SIGUSR1. Since POSIX specifies that signals will be delivered to a thread which is not blocking the signal, it will be delivered to one of the threads waiting in sigwait(). There is thus no need to keep track of which threads have already received the signal and which haven't, with associated synchronization.

Comment: thanks , it seems that pthread_sigmask is a system call and this synchronization has lower overhead than mutex/fuex/semaphore ?

Comment: @user1000107: No, I don't think so. Uncontended futexes don't require a syscall and should be as fast as a few cpu synchronization instructions (cas, barriers, etc.), so it's hard to beat that for a general purpose synchronization mechanism.

Comment: pthread_sigmask has some advantages over mutex, semaphore ? thanks !

Comment: @user1000107, signals are generally speaking worse than mutexes or semaphores. They tend to be slower and more complex to use. But since you've said uou can't use mutexes or semaphores, well, they're an option.

Comment: @bdonlan, Why signals are slower than mutex or semaphore ? They need more system calls ?  What other ways can be used for synchronization faster than mutex or semaphore ? futex ? or else ? thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using SSE3's `MONITOR` and `MWAIT` instructions, available via the [`_mm_mwait`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/7d7ytc18%28v=vs.80%29) and [`_mm_monitor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88w8339f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) intrinsics, Intel has an article on it [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-to-use-the-monitor-and-mwait-streaming-simd-extensions-3-instructions/).
(there is also a patent for using memory-monitor-wait for lock contention [here](http://www.google.com/patents/US20040267996) that may be of interest).

Comment: This is a nifty feature.  Someday I know it or something similar will be useful.  Thanks!

Comment: @Necrolis , these instructions are for windows, what if linux/unix ?

Comment: @user1000107: these instructions are for **x86 & SSE3**, they have nothing to do with windows, I just chose to use the MSDN docs for the intrinsics available in MSVC, they should be the same under ICC (which works under Linux & OSX)

Comment: @Necrolis, so SSE3 is faster than mutex, semaphore or futex ? if no, what is its advantages ? it has no system call in the case of no contention ? thanks !

Comment: @user1000107: I have no clue about performance (Agner Fog's listings might have info on that), however, `MWAIT` generally provides power savings. `MONITOR` & `MWAIT` are instructions, there is no call at all when using them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking the [Peterson's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm) or [Dekker's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dekker%27s_algorithm)

They synced threads only based on shared memory